# The Dirichlet's problem in the Riemannian setting

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Is the Dirichlet's problem solved in full generality? i.e let $M,N$ be compact oriented Riemannian manifolds with boundary, and let $\psi:\partial M \to N$ be smooth.

Is there always a harmonic map $\phi:M \to N$ which agrees with $\psi$ on $
\partial M$? Are there some sufficient conditions which ensure solutions exist?

Somehow, I did not find a definitive reference. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

As explained below there are some topological and differential-topological obstructions. So, suppose $\psi$ is the restriction of a smooth orientation-preserving immersion $M \to N$.

Even in this case, harmonic maps do not always exist:

Take $M=[0,1]$, $N$ a flat annulus in the Euclidean plane. Then, harmonic maps $M \to N$ are geodesics. Choose $\psi(0),\psi(1)$ to be two points such that no geodesic exist between them (the geodesics in $N$ are standard straight segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $N$ is not convex, so just pick two points s.t the connecting segment between them does not lie entirely in $N$ ).

---

**Obstructions:**

As commented by levap, there are topological obstructions.

For example, if $M$ is a two-dimensional disc and $N=\mathbb{S}^1$ then a map $\psi:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ must be null-homotopic in order to admit a continuous extension to $M$.

Moreover, existence of a continuous extension does not always ensure existence of a smooth extension, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206645/can-we-extend-smooth-maps-when-the-target-manifold-has-boundary) .

Comment: This is too general to expect by mere topological considerations. For example, if $M$ is a two-dimensional disc and $N = S^1$ then a map $\psi \colon S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ must be null-homotopic in order to admit a continuous extension to $M$, not to mention a harmonic one. I'm pretty sure that even if you are in the situation that a topological extension is possible, you won't necessarily be able to find a harmonic extension but I don't have an example off the top of my head.

Comment: Another problem might arise in the cases when $N$ has non-empty boundary. Take for example $N$ to be a flat annulus and $M = [0,1]$. I'm not even sure how harmonic maps are/should be defined in this context (you know about manifolds with boundary much more than I do), but the naive definition implies that $\phi$ should be a smooth geodesic connecting $\phi(0)$ to $\phi(1)$ but we can choose $\phi(0),\phi(1)$ so that no such geodesic exists.