# Can we extend smooth maps when the target manifold has boundary?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds with boundary. Let $A \subseteq N$ be closed, and let $f:A \to M$ be a smooth map.

Suppose $f$ has a continuous extension to $N$. Does it have a smooth extension to $N$?

In case the target manifold $M$ has no boundary, this is known to be true (See corollary 6.27 in Lee's book introduction to smooth manifolds).

I am asking about the case where $M$ has non-empty boundary.

Comment: I don't understand something. Consider the absolute value $ |.| : [-1,1] \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb (-1,2)$. This is a smooth map which admit a continuous extension but no smooth extension. Am I mistaken ?

Comment: Note that your subset $A$ where $f$ is defined is not closed... Indeed your example shows this is a necessary condition for the theorem to hold

Comment: Oh I didn't read it carefully. Sorry for the stupid remark !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. Here's a counterexample. Let $M=[0,\infty)$, $N=\mathbb R$, $A=[0,\infty)$, and define $f\colon A\to M$ by $f(x)=x$.  Then $f$ has a continuous extension to $N$, for example
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x, & x\ge 0,\\
0, & x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
But it has no smooth extension. If $F\colon \mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ were a smooth extension of $f$, then considered as a real-valued function $F$ would take a global minimum at $0$ so its derivative would be zero there. But by continuity of the derivative, 
$$
F'(0) = \lim_{x\searrow 0} F'(x) = \lim_{x\searrow 0} f'(x) = 1.
$$